# Ansible: list Jinja2 filters using the CLI

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

While developing with Ansible, I would like to be able to use the CLI entirely to lookup information without having to Google something every 5 minutes.

I often use the `ansible-doc` command to get information about built-in modules, Ansible keywords, etc. and `ansible-config` when I have to write an `ansible.cfg` file. Unfortunately, I cannot find anything related to Jinja2 filters.

##### Question

How can I get a list of all Jinja2 filters without relying solely on my memory in case I do not have access to a browser or I'm sitting a Red Hat exam?

Comment: I do not think `ansible` provide documentation over command line for `jinja2` filters. There is a "raw" way to figure out the details over the command line. For this you need to know the python package location of `jinja2` in your node.


    `grep -zo  'FILTERS.*' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/filters.py`, there are comments on each filter in this file for example and details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've long wished that `ansible-doc` had a `-t filters` option, too, but I think that's unlikely to happen since the filters are in a unique situation given that jinja2 itself has filters then ansible layers extra filters on top of the built-in jinja2 ones using its plugins mechanism. That story only gets worse with the new ansible-collections split

There are (at least) two work-arounds I can offer for the offline case:

1. the pydoc command
2. brute force `find`

### using pydoc

You can identify the python interpreter that ansible, itself, is using via `ansible --version` and look for `ansible python module location`. While that path will point to the `.../site-packages/ansible` directory, it will still help know if ansible is in a virtualenv (as Brew does), in `$HOME/.local`, or against which system python version one should look

*In these snippets, I'm going to be using just bare `python`, but in the actual case it would be the fully-qualified path to the python binary ansible uses*

Then, enumerate the jinja2 filters via

```sh
python -m pydoc jinja2.filters
```

and the non-collection ansible filters by first getting the top-level package:

```sh
$ PAGER=cat python -m pydoc ansible.plugins.filter
Help on package ansible.plugins.filter in ansible.plugins:

NAME
    ansible.plugins.filter - # Make coding more python3-ish

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    core
    mathstuff
    urls
    urlsplit
```

and then iterate on the filter packages

```sh
for i in core mathstuff urls urlsplit; do
  python -m pydoc ansible.plugins.filter.$i
done
```

That technique will also print the actual python source code path at the bottom of the output, if you need to dig into the actual implementation detail for any nuance or memory-jog

I had some limited success using this trickery to find potential filter plugins out of the installed collections

```sh
ansible-galaxy collection list | \
    sed 's/^/ansible_collections./; s/  *[0-9].*/.plugins.filter/'
```

but obviously not all of those packages are correct or even exist

### brute force using `find`

The newfound split into ansible-collections makes getting *the whole list* harder using that pydoc method, but they are still on-disk python files so you can use the `path` predicate to locate the ones which provide filter plugins:

```sh
for p in $(ansible --version | awk -F= '/ansible .* location/{gsub(":", "\n", $2); print $2}'); do
  find ${p}* -path '*/plugins/filter/*' -name '*.py' 2>/dev/null
done
```

which will serve as a memory jog, a place to read the source, and targets for using the aforementioned `pydoc` technique, if you prefer